# include Qt Plugin/Libraries in Project

Tags: c++, windows, qt

is there any way to include plugin and Qt's libraries in project ? I'd like to make executable that will be like portable. I don't like RarSFX, or things like that. Is there any other way to do it? I've heard that I can put DLLs in projects resources and use from there, but I don't know how to do that. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean embedding them into the executable?

Comment: You want to link Qt libraries with your application statically. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_library

Comment: Nikos C. Yes, embedding them to project, so it can use them from resources.
divanov, some of libraries is not available for static linkink. for example QWebPage. I just need to embed them into project.

Comment: Is there only WebKit not allowed to be linked statically?